# Is there a way to get the Visual Studio code terminal to quit asking for favicon.ico

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, http-status-code-404, favicon

Using vsCode for JavaScript. Everytime I open live server in the terminal I get "GET/favicon.ico" which always leads to a 404 error since I don't have a favicon. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers such as Chrome request "favicon.ico" by default.

If you are working on some site that does not need a favicon, here are some workarounds.

1. add the line: `<link rel="icon" href="data:,">` to the `head` of all your html files

Since you mentioned settings, here are a couple things you can do to quickly get rid of the 404:

2. Chrome Network tab -> right click "favicon.ico"

- select `Block request url` [you can disable this later]

3. Live Server settings > Settings: File

- enter some other default file or `/` [dangerous, not recommended for this case]

Keep in mind, the last two solutions will likely catch up to you if you actually want the default behavior to let you know when you did not add a favicon.

Comment: Thank you. Option one was the easiest since only one html file was involved and your solution did the trick.